# How to marge 3rd call in android

Tags: android

when user making an call if **another call came to his phone from a particulate no is should be automatically merged**. I already implemented listening a particular no I need to marge it.Is it possible?

Comment: By merging, you mean call conference?

Comment: yes I mean to say call conference

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not at the moment AFAIK.  Call conference is managed by the system and is inaccessible to developers.  I think you already used [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html), but you are only really able to access basic information about the phone.

This may be mainly for security reasons (so people can't "bug" phones with a simple program), and also because telephony is managed on a lower level, within the kernel.